# If A is finite then Conv(A) is compact

Tags: calculus, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, compactness

Let $\left(V,||\cdot||\right)$ be norm space. Let $A\subseteq V$. We define the Convex of A to be:
$$Conv(A)= \{\sum^n_{j=1} \alpha_j v_j : N\geq 1, \alpha_1,...,\alpha_N\ge 0,\sum^n_{j=1}\alpha_j =1, and v_1,...,v_N \in A  \} $$
The smallest convex set which contains A. I need to prove that if A is finite 
then Conv(A) is compact.

My try:

There's non-countable amount of elements in conv(A).
Let $c_n$ be a sequence in Conv(A)  $c_1,c_2,c_3,...$
$$c_1=\alpha_{11}v_1,\alpha_{12}v_2,...,\alpha_{1N}v_N$$
$$c_2=\alpha_{21}v_1,\alpha_{22}v_2,...,\alpha_{2N}v_N$$
$$c_3=\alpha_{31}v_1,\alpha_{32}v_2,...,\alpha_{3N}v_N$$
$$\vdots$$
Note that for each line $\alpha_j \in [0,1]$.
We denote the "column sequence" of coefficients 
$alpha_{11},\alpha_{21}...$  with $C_{n}(1)$.
and the "column sequence" of coefficients $\alpha_{12},\alpha_{22}...$  with $C_n(2)$ and so on for each column.
As we can see from Conv(A) definition we have that for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1\le n \le N$ - $\alpha_{kn}\in [0,1]$ , we know that $[0,1]$ is compact 
and hence every sequence in $[0,1]$ has a a convergent subsquence. So there
exists strictly increasing sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ , $n_k$  such that $C_{n_{k}}(1)$ converging to some $x_1 \in [0,1]$, Now we look at $C_{n_{k}}(2)$
 we know it has convergent sub sequence to some $x_2$ in $[0,1]$ we do that again and again N times and then we have a subsequence in Conv(A) that converges to an element in Conv(A). I'm struggling with making it formal.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are rediscovering Bolzano-Weierstrass's theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $Conv(A)$ is closed and bounded subset of the finite dimensional vector subspace since it is include in the vector subspace generated by $v_1,...,v_N$.

$\|\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}a_iv_i\|\leq \sum|a_i\|v_i\|\leq\sum_{i=1}^{i=n}\|v_i\|$ since $|a_i|\leq 1$.

Comment: It cannot be a subspace because it doesn't contain the zero vector

Comment: And I think it is not so easy to prove "closed" directly from the definition.

Comment: Then how would you suggest proving "closed"?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Delta_N = \{ (\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_N) \colon \alpha_j \ge 0 \text{ for } j \in \{1, \dots, N\}, \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j = 1 \}$. Let a map
\begin{align*}
T \colon &\Delta_N \times \underbrace{ A \times \cdots \times A }_{N \text{times}} \to \mathbb{R},
\end{align*}
be given by $(\Delta_N, a_1, \dots, a_N) \mapsto \sum_{j=1}^N \alpha_j a_j$. We note the image of $T$ is exactly $\text{conv}(A)$. Since $T$ is continuous and $\Delta_N \times A \times \dots \times A$ is compact ($\Delta_N$ and $A$ are compact), $\text{conv}(A)$ is compact.